# NSError localizedDescription always returns english error message

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nserror

Why does an NSError * error object with NSURLErrorDomain always return the error.localizedDescription in english ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question can be found in the project settings. You have to add the language you are interested in to your project Settings:

- Select the Project in the left navigate
- select the project (not the target)
- select the "Info" pane
- add the language to the "localization" section

Answer (score 1):

Language is the first available in your project according to your languages order in the settings

Answer (score 0):

In your "iOS Simulator" (or in your testing device) start "Settings" app and select the required testing language.
Start your app again and you will get the correct localised Description.